# Make multiple Elements fire events as one

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I've got a parent control (panel) which has several child controls (propably only labels).

Now I want to use Drag and Drop and if possibly even hover effects on the parent control. If I only assign the needed events to the parent class the handlers won't be executed if a child causes the event (e.g. clicking on a label won't fire the panels click event).

I tried just adding one big element on top of everything else which covers the panel completely (and thus catches every event), but then you can't see the child elements anymore since Windows Forms doesn't support real transparency.

What is the cleanest way to make all these elements behave like one regarding events and drag and drop?

Comment: Create a single handler method and assign all the events to that method.

Comment: In that case i'd have to assign the events to the childs as well which could cause multiple events to fire when i only want it once (e.g. multiple MouseLeaves, one for every child and one for the parent)

Comment: It sounds like maybe you dont know which event you want to handle.  Are you handling a Drop event or a MouseLeaves event? Which event are you trying to handle?

Comment: Multiple. I want drag n drop and hover effects.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it now, you want to have multiple controls inside a Panel and when you drag the Panel control, you want everything inside it to move *with* the Panel? You'll get that functionality with a standard Drag/Drop actions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool isMouseDown;
        Point lastPoint = new Point(0,0);

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = true;
            lastPoint = e.Location;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMouseDown)
            {
                panel1.Location = new Point(
                    (
                    panel1.Location.X + e.X) - lastPoint.X,
                    (panel1.Location.Y + e.Y) - lastPoint.Y);

                this.Update();
            }
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isMouseDown = false;

        }
    }
}
```

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Label l = new Label();
    l.MouseDown += l.MouseDown;
    l.MouseMove += l.MouseMove;
    l.MouseUp += l.MouseUp;
    panel1.Controls.Add(l);
}
```

}
    void l_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
        lastPoint = e.Location;
    }

```
void l_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMouseDown)
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(
                (
                panel1.Location.X + e.X) - lastPoint.X,
                (panel1.Location.Y + e.Y) - lastPoint.Y);

        ((Label)sender).Location = new Point(((Label)sender).Location.X + e.X) - lastPoint.X, ((Label)sender).Location.Y + e.Y) - lastPoint.Y));

            this.Update();
        }
}

void l_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = false;
}
```

Paste this into a new WinForms project and throw a Panel onto the form and add some Label controls to it. I've tested this and everything inside the panel movies with it when the Panel is dragged.

Comment: This will only move a single label at a time. The OP wants to move the parent panel when either the panel itself is dragged or any of the contained labels.

Comment: Updated. If you don't want to dynamically generate these Labels at runtime - then the other alternative is to find all controls you want this effect with inside the panel, probably using `panel1.Controls.Find(<String>)` and then hooking up MouseDown, Move and Up events to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly this kind of thing before. The way I do it is use Microsoft's reactive framework to smooth out all of the hard work of handling the events from multiple controls and then querying them in an easy way.

So first up, you need to use NuGet to add the "Rx-WinForms" package to your project and a `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to your code.

You then create an array of the controls you want to be active in the drag & drop:

```
        var controls = new Control[]
        {
            panel1, label1, label2, label3,
        };
```

Now we need to know when there are `MouseMove`, `MouseDown`, and `MouseUp` events for any of these controls. This is where the Reactive Framework comes in. We need three `IObservable<MouseEventArgs>` for each of these events aggregated over all of the controls.

Here's the code for that:

```
        IObservable<MouseEventArgs> moves =
            controls
                .Select(c =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                            h => c.MouseMove += h,
                            h => c.MouseMove -= h))
                .Merge()
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

        IObservable<MouseEventArgs> downs =
            controls
                .Select(c =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                            h => c.MouseDown += h,
                            h => c.MouseDown -= h))
                .Merge()
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);

        IObservable<MouseEventArgs> ups =
            controls
                .Select(c =>
                    Observable
                        .FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                            h => c.MouseUp += h,
                            h => c.MouseUp -= h))
                .Merge()
                .Select(x => x.EventArgs);
```

That might seem like a bit of yucky code, but it makes the next part almost too simple:

```
        IObservable<Point> deltas =
            from down in downs
            from move in moves.TakeUntil(ups)
            select new Point
            {
                X = move.X - down.X,
                Y = move.Y - down.Y
            };
```

Basically this reads as "when I get a mouse down, followed by mouse moves until I get a mouse up, then give me the relative co-ordinates where the mouse now is compared to the point where the mouse down occurred."

Now I can just subscribe to that stream of deltas and reposition the panel:

```
        IDisposable subscription =
            deltas
                .Subscribe(d =>
                {
                    panel1.SetBounds(
                        panel1.Location.X + d.X,
                        panel1.Location.Y + d.Y,
                        0,
                        0,
                        BoundsSpecified.Location);
                });
```

The Reactive Framework handles all of the wiring up of the events for you. All you have to clean up is call `.Dispose()` on the `subscription` variable to completely detach all of the event handlers.

Once you get your head around what is going on this kind of coding becomes much simpler than the standard event handler approach.

The other nice thing is that all of the code is in a single method, most likely your "Form_Load", so you don't end up with huge amounts of spaghetti.